# word 2010 interop : edit word document header

Tags: interop, ms-word, dsoframer

I am using word 2010 and DSOFramer control to embedded word document in winforms application and I have to enter the header edit mode I am using the code below :

```
if (wordDocument.ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial != WdSpecialPane.wdPaneNone)
    wordDocument.ActiveWindow.Panes[2].Close();
  if (wordDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type == WdViewType.wdNormalView ||
    wordDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type == WdViewType.wdOutlineView)
    wordDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = WdViewType.wdPrintView;
  wordDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageHeader;
```

but the application become unresponsive when executing this line :

wordDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageHeader;

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Solution can be found here [Word 2010 header edition](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/worddev/thread/6f0939d1-e513-43bc-991f-403b72cbf848)